# Acessar todas as linhas de uma tabela JAVAFX

Tags: java, javafx

Possuo a seguinte tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar em um botão, quero que uma função execute a cada linha lida:

```
    private void inserirResultadosUsuario() {
    //Necessário pegar o valor de cada linha e de cada coluna por  vez              
}
```

Código do controller completo:

```
@FXML private Button btnSalvar;
@FXML private TableView<Partida> tabela;   
@FXML private TextField txtRodada;
@FXML private Button btnRodadas;
@FXML private TableColumn<Partida, String> clmTime1;
@FXML private TableColumn<Partida, Integer> clmPlacar1;
@FXML private TableColumn<String, String> clmX;
@FXML private TableColumn<Partida, Integer> clmPlacar2;
@FXML private TableColumn<Partida, String> clmTime2;

public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    clmTime1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("cod_time1"));
    clmPlacar1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("gol_time1"));
    clmX.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("X"));
    clmPlacar2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("gol_time2"));
    clmTime2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("cod_time2"));      
}

@FXML
private void refreshTable() {
    ArrayList<Partida> listaPartida = new partidaDAO().listarPartidas();
    ObservableList<Partida> observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(listaPartida);
    tabela.setItems(observableList);        
}

@FXML
private void mostrarTabelaDeAcordoComRodada() {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(txtRodada.getText());
    ArrayList<Partida> listarPartidaEspecifica = partidaDAO.listarPartidasEspecifica(i);
    ObservableList<Partida> observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(listarPartidaEspecifica);
    tabela.setItems(observableList);
}

@FXML
private void inserirResultadosUsuario() {

}
```

Como poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Essa tabela é composta por uma lista de algum item,  Sendo assim : 
`List<Item> lista ;`

No método que é chamado pelo seu botão você vai fazer o seguinte :

```
itens.forEach(item -> inserirResultadosUsuario());
```

Assim existe a garantia de que para cada item dessa lista o método inserirResultadosUsuario foi executado.

Comment: Dei uma olhada aqui e não consegui visualizar como fazer essa mudança, eu alterei o post original com o controller completo, consegue dar uma olhada?

Comment: tenta o seguinte tabela.getItems().forEach(item -> inserirResultadosUsuario());
Diz se dá algum erro